# create log file name with current date using appenders path present in log4rs YAML configuration file

Tags: rust, rust-cargo, rust-tokio

I want to add the current date to the log file name using log4rs library based on YAML configuration file. Although we perform daily rollovers, the current log file lacks a date. The format for the log file name would be **logs/Application.2023-01-04.log** . But using the below code i am getting file name as same whatever i have given in path filed. Any idea on this?

Please find the code i am using below.

```
refresh_rate: 600 seconds
appenders:
stdout:
kind: console
encoder:
pattern: "{d(%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S)(utc)} - | {h({l}):5} | {f}:{L} — {m}{n}"
file_logger:
kind: file
path: "logs/Application.{d}-{m}-{n}.log"
encoder:
pattern: "{d(%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S)(utc)} - | {h({l}):5} | {f}:{L} — {m}{n}"
root:
level: info
appenders:
- stdout
- file_logger
```

Answer (score 0):

No, this is currently not possible. There is however an issue tracking the development of the feature: https://github.com/estk/log4rs/issues/242